# I have this code, how can I transfer it from console to GUI in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, median, mode

I have this code, done and functions really well on console but I need to transfer it to GUI, for example I have 4 operations, which are calculating and processing median, mode, mean and standard deviation. As a result of that, I need to have 4 text field inputs and one button calculating the 4 operations and display either on the program itself or pop up.

```java
import javax.sound.midi.SysexMessage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FinalProg {

    Button button;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


//        int[] dataSet = {1,2,3,4,345,312,756,0,-234321132,234};
//        int[] dataSet = {5,3,2,5,2,5,758,345,32,231,5,5,5,2,2};

//        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//        String input = scanner.nextLine();
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//        int [] dataSet = new int[input.length()];

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine(); //Numbers inputted from user in your case
        String[] list;             //List to store individual numbers
        list = input.split(" ");     // Regex to split the String so you get each number

        //Mean
        int sum = 0;

        for (String n : list) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(n);
        }

        System.out.println("The mean of the data set is  " +
                ((double) sum / list.length));


        //Median
        Arrays.sort(list);
//            if (list.length  % 2 != 0) {
//                System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2]));
//            } else {
//                float median = (Integer.parseInt(list[list.length/2]+Integer.parseInt(list[(list.length/2)-1])) / 2f );
//                System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + median);
////                System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2] + list[list.length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0);
//            }

        if (list.length % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2]) + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2 - 1]) / 2);
        } else {
//                float median = (Integer.parseInt(list[list.length/2]+Integer.parseInt(list[(list.length/2)-1])) / 2f );
            System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + list[list.length / 2]);
//                System.out.println("The median of the data set is: " + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2] + list[list.length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0);
        }


        //Mode

        int maxNumber = -1;
        int maxAppearances = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
//                    if (list[i] == list[j]) {
//                        count++;
//                    }
                if (list[i].equals(list[j])) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > maxAppearances) {
                maxNumber = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
                maxAppearances = count;
            }
            count = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("The mode of the data set: " + maxNumber);


        //STDV

        double STDVsum = 0.0, standardDeviation = 0.0;
        int length = list.length;
        for (String num : list) {
            STDVsum += Double.parseDouble(num);
        }
        double mean = STDVsum / length;
//        for(String num: list) {
//            standardDeviation += Double.parseDouble(Math.pow(num - mean, 2)); // It says operator - doesn't apply...
//        }
        for (String num : list) {
            int num_to_Integer = Integer.parseInt(num);
            standardDeviation += Math.pow(num_to_Integer - mean, 2); //No need to parse now
        }
        System.out.println("STDV " + Math.sqrt(standardDeviation / length));

    }



}
```

Comment: Or JavaFx. You can learn it from thousands of video tutorials on Youtube or from any java book on gui. Since you have come this far it won't be that difficult. You'll get hang of it pretty easily.

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from a console program to the GUI program requires a lot more than just changing main methods. GUI programs are event-driven.

What I mean by event-driven is, for example, a button gets pressed, an event is fired. You as the programmer are responsible for coding what happens when that event is fired.

So some advice from me.

- You should go through the tutorials and learn some of the basic
  [components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) and how they work. Some of the basic ones are [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html),
  [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- You will definitely need to focus on how to write [event listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html).
  Some of the basic ones you may want to focus on are [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for button presses [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for mouse events.
- You can use [Java Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to easily create a form and implement its
  functionality. And it is always a good place to start. Once you pick up on the basics, then move on to some more complex material.
- Use some advanced IDE's like [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/), [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/), [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), etc. Here are some basic projects to start from [NetBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/settingup.html).

So technically, if I come to your question,

You can convert your console application to GUI application using *Java Swing*.

- You are getting inputs from the console. Instead of that, you can use
  `JTextFields` or `JTextArea` as you wish to get the input.
- And you can use some `JButtons` to trigger the process that needs to
  do after filling the JTextFields.
- Instead of writing to the console what you'd normally write you can use `JTextArea` to write what you wrote on the console. And if you have series or sentences you can use JTextArea's [append()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) method.

So here is the code that I created in Swing using NetBeans IDE,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackOverflow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String[] list;

    /**
     * Creates new form StackOverflow
     */
    public StackOverflow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        inputTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        scrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        consoleTxt = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        stdvBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        modeBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        medianBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        meanBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        inputTxt.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                inputTxtKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        consoleTxt.setColumns(20);
        consoleTxt.setRows(5);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(consoleTxt);

        stdvBtn.setText("STDV");
        stdvBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                stdvBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        modeBtn.setText("Mode");
        modeBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                modeBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        medianBtn.setText("Median");
        medianBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                medianBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        meanBtn.setText("Mean");
        meanBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                meanBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
        mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(inputTxt)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 370, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(meanBtn)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(medianBtn)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(modeBtn)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(stdvBtn)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(inputTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(scrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 78, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(stdvBtn)
                    .addComponent(modeBtn)
                    .addComponent(medianBtn)
                    .addComponent(meanBtn))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(730, 381));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void inputTxtKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        list = inputTxt.getText().split(" ");
    }                                    

    private void meanBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        int sum = 0;

        for (String n : list) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(n);
        }
        consoleTxt.append("The mean of the data set is  " + ((double) sum / list.length) + "\n");
    }                                       

    private void medianBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        Arrays.sort(list);

        if (list.length % 2 == 0) {
            consoleTxt.append("The median of the data set is: " + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2]) + Double.parseDouble(list[list.length / 2 - 1]) / 2 + "\n");
        } else {
            consoleTxt.append("The median of the data set is: " + list[list.length / 2] + "\n");
        }
    }                                         

    private void modeBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        int maxNumber = -1;
        int maxAppearances = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (list[i].equals(list[j])) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > maxAppearances) {
                maxNumber = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
                maxAppearances = count;
            }
            count = 0;
        }

        consoleTxt.append("The mode of the data set: " + maxNumber + "\n");
    }                                       

    private void stdvBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        double STDVsum = 0.0, standardDeviation = 0.0;
        int length = list.length;

        for (String num : list) {
            STDVsum += Double.parseDouble(num);
        }

        double mean = STDVsum / length;

        for (String num : list) {
            int num_to_Integer = Integer.parseInt(num);
            standardDeviation += Math.pow(num_to_Integer - mean, 2);
        }

        consoleTxt.append("STDV " + Math.sqrt(standardDeviation / length) + "\n");
    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StackOverflow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StackOverflow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StackOverflow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(StackOverflow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new StackOverflow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextArea consoleTxt;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inputTxt;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton meanBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton medianBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton modeBtn;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JButton stdvBtn;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

If you go through the code,

> Used components `JTextField`, `JTextArea`, `JButton`, `JPanel`,
>   `JFrame`.

```
private javax.swing.JTextArea consoleTxt;
private javax.swing.JTextField inputTxt;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton meanBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton medianBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton modeBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton stdvBtn;
```

> Used `ActionListeners` to trigger the functions.

For an example [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to call a function (find the mean in your case) once the mean button pressed it will trigger the `meanBtnActionPerformed(evt);` function.

```
meanBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                meanBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
```

What inside the `meanBtnActionPerformed(evt);`.

```
private void meanBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        int sum = 0;

        for (String n : list) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(n);
        }
        consoleTxt.append("The mean of the data set is  " + ((double) sum / list.length) + "\n");
    }
```

And another main thing is, in your console application when you type the numbers and enter it then the `String[] list` will populate. So to do that I have used [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). The key events are fired by the component with the keyboard focus when the user presses or releases keyboard keys. So in your case when you type like `10 20 30 40 50` it will add those numbers to the list by calling `inputTxtKeyReleased(evt);` function.

```
inputTxt.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                inputTxtKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });
```

So I suggest to examine the code, try it, go through the java docs and learn from the tutorials. Happy Coding!

Comment: Man, you're a savior! you don't how much I was worried about it. Thank you so much for doing it and explaining it as well.

Comment: Pleased to know it helped brother :)